# Probability 10 teams "splitting" two series each

Tags: probability

[I saw this on reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/CollegeBasketball/comments/5vqw4k/big_12_has_completed_a_two_way_circle_of_suck/)

Basically, there are 10 teams. Each team plays each other team twice, so every team has 18 games and "9 two-game series." What happened in this scenario is each team "split" at least two series, creating this circle that creates a win/loss chain connecting every team in both directions. I was trying to find the probability that this event occurs, assuming for simplicity that each game has a 50/50 outcome.

My attempt was this: the probability of a series split is $2*.5^{2} = .5$, so the probability that a team ends up with at least two splits would be binomial with $N=9, p=.5, x=2.$

$P(X>=2)=.9805$

Then the probability that all teams would split would be $.9805^{10}=.8212$

I'm pretty sure this isn't correct, this seems like a complicated scenario with a lot of things to factor in. I think there would be scenarios where all teams split more than twice, but this circle is not possible.

How would you approach this? I've been stumped on this for a while now, maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: The probability of a series spilt is $2 \times 0.5^2=0.5$

Comment: @Henry correct, I just overlooked that somehow. Updated my question

Comment: There are $\frac{(10-1)!}{2}$ ways of choosing a Hamiltonian cycle on the complete graph.  Why are you not simply multiplying that by $0.5^{10 \choose 2}$ ?

Comment: @Henry, I was not familiar with a Hamiltonian cycle. Why the $0.5^{{10}\choose{2}}$?

Comment: Because there are $45$ pairs of teams

Comment: @Henry I don't see why $.5^{45}$ would be correct. We would need each team to "split" exactly two times. So out of the 45 pairs of teams, 10 of them would need to be "splits", but not just any 10 (two for each team).

Comment: What is the probability of all of  the other $35$ series being "not-splits"?

Comment: @Henry I see that, I guess it just doesn't seem right to me for some reason, but you are probably correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry, thinking about it more, I believe I was wrong in saying exactly two splits. A team could split more than two times and you could still complete this circle. So I should've said, what's the probability that each team has at least two splits?